# How to deploy python flask application on linux web app service through azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy my flask application on Linux web apps.
I want to set a azure pipeline for my code which is pushed on an azure repository.

I have made all the configuration changes in my python code and created a web app with runtime stack of Python 3.7

As soon as I go to deployment center to deploy my code, after selecting the azure repository as the source of my code, I am redirected to an option of azure pipelines where we have to configure our build settings.

But the build does not gives any option for Python. It just gives me four build options such as Node, Ruby, Asp.Net and php.

I cannot use :
- Docker
- Git

With such limitations I have found no suitable tutorial to do the same.

Can someone tell me some way to set the pipeline for my python project ?

Comment: Hi, just want to check whether below solution and blog could help you achieve the python application deployed successfully now? Any issue or puzzle still facing? Feel free to leave comment below if you still has any puzzle:-)

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Hi, I have followed the below steps but still no luck . The pipeline succeeds but when we hit the endpoint the page displays:  :( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

Comment: This seems a error from Azure rather than VSTS. Did you find anything abnormal from azure log? I may involved my colleague which from azure team, if you could update some error info more.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT The diagnostics logs give no further error information .

Comment: As confirmed with my Azure team colleague, it is a issue relevant with Azure configuration(I work for azure devops not azure). You’d better submit a separate one new ticket for that error because it is a separated issue. Then other communities could help for that. In addition, if you think the steps of this ticket could useful for others who has same puzzle about how to deploy the python app. You can [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/541930).

Comment: Welcome. If need any assistance about azure from me or my team. Feel free to leave comment. Will try best to give you some guide as much as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DevOps CI/CD works with any language, platform and cloud. Just for Python application, you may need add additional steps to achieve the deployment from Azure Devops CI/CD.

---

- **CI**

Since the python is an interpreted language, do not need the compilation. If none of other step, like test, just need use 2 tasks in CI pipeline: [Archive Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) task and [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) task.

[image]

The **Archive Files task** used to **pack** the python application source folder into a zip package to use it in CD. And **Publish Build Artifacts task** will **publish** this zip package to Release pipeline.

BUT,

If your project contains and needs test, please add another [Command line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) to run the test by using [**pytest**](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/).

But, in azure devops, you need configure the python environment with some tasks if you want to use python component like **pytest**.

Here please refer to this [blog](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/python/).

Note: Since the stack you are using is `Python 3.7`, please specify the python version as `3.x` in the Using Python task.

---

- **CD**

*Since you have create the app service in Azure portal, just **skip step 4(Add Azure CLI task)** in **Exercise 3: Configure Release pipeline** which shown in this [blog](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/python/), because Step 4 just used to create a new Azure Resources.*

**1.** To deploy the python application, you need add the [Azure App Service manage](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureAppServiceManageV0/README.md) task first to install the corresponding python version site extension in release pipeline:

[image]

It would install set of corresponding tools to support to manage your app service.

**2.** Next you could use [Azure App Service deploy](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/README.md) to deploy the **zip** package which created in the Build pipeline, to the app service you configured in Azure portal.

After specified the subscription in this task, the app service will automatically display in the drop list of **App Service name**:

[image]

Then specified the path which you configured in the publish task of the build pipeline. Replace `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, and replace `$(Build.BuildId)` as `*` to search the `zip` package by using the fuzzy search.

[image]

Comment: how to run `pip install` on target machine from azure devops?